# Web Service for Geo Location (Get biggest Cities within an state)

Tags: geolocation

Is there are (web) service which offers a Geo Location API?

For example: 
I have the German State "Baden-Württemberg", now I want to get a result which are the biggest city's (for example order by population).

My problem is little bit abstract, but hope someone can understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly what you are looking for, but I think it is a step in the direction if you are willing to setup your own database to query. The United Nations Statistical Division (UNSD) keeps a dataset of the largest cities > 100,000 population. You can find it at this link. Note that it does not show what state (1st level administrative division) the city is within, just the country.

http://unstats.un.org/unsd/demographic/products/dyb/dyb2011/Table08.xls

I have created a CSV version of the data (using semi-colons as delims) you can use as well:

http://www.opengeocode.org/cude1.1/UN/UNSD/dyd2011-pop100k.zip

OpenGeoCode.Org is an open data project where we take national and international publicly available datasets and convert them into a common CSV format.

Andrew

Comment: OpenGeoCode.org is a nice solution. Thanx Andrew.